Как перенести юзера в канал после его создания discord.py
У меня есть скрипт который создает канал:
await categoty.create_text_channel(name=f'channel')
channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=f"channel")

Вопрос:
как сделать так, чтобы после его создания юзера переместило в канал?

Перемещение пользователя из канала в канал возможно только в том случае, если перемещаемый канал типа VoiceChannel. Иными словами: такое можно сделать только с голосовыми каналами.

то-есть чтобы текстовый канал открылся на экране у юзера-никак?\

@ЯковТерехов Да. Но можно сделать костыль в виде отправки сообщения с ссылкой на канал:
"<#{channel_id}>"
